# Can I set a variable "Expires" in Amazon S3?

Tags: http-headers, amazon-s3, expires

I have a ton of files in Amazon S3 (served via Cloudfront) for which I have added an Expires header of `Mon, Jan 1 2024 11:11:11 GMT`

However, I have recently learned that setting an Expires header more than one year in the future violates the [HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21).

So is there a way in S3 to set a dynamic Expires that is always one year from the request date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So is there a way in S3 to set a dynamic Expires that is always one
>   year from the request date?

Not that I know of, and I doubt that dedicated support for this will be considered by the AWS team:

You are probably aware that one can't set a dynamic `Expires: ...` value as such because *The only value valid in an Expires header is a HTTP date; anything else will most likely be interpreted as ‘in the past’, so that the representation is uncacheable.* (see  e.g. [Controlling Freshness with the Expires HTTP Header](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#EXPIRES) within Mark Nottingham's excellent [Caching Tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)).

However, this weakness of the HTTP 1.0 `Expires: ...` header has been realized and remedied in HTTP 1.1, which *introduced a new class of headers, Cache-Control response headers, to give Web publishers more control over their content, and to address the limitations of Expires.* (see [Cache-Control HTTP Headers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL)).

So concerning your use case (and in general), I'd strongly recommend resorting to a `Cache-Control: max-age=...` header for one year in the future first and only add `Expires: ...` for backward compatibility, if there is a specific reason to do so. In this case however, according to your question, you'll indeed have to adjust the value once in a while to avoid violating the HTTP 1.1 RFC, e.g. via a script targeting the [S3 API](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/).

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. One more quick question: do you know if "public" is necessary in the Cache-control directive, or is that the default? i.e. `Cache-control: public, max-age=3600`

Comment: It is not the default as such, rather cacheability depends on the context (e.g. default is private for HTTP authenticated requests) - the details are a bit complex, see [What is Cacheable?](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1) and [Response Cacheability](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.4), i.e. it's _sort of_ implied in most scenarios, but concerning your use case it seems reasonable to add it, insofar you'd probably want to cache authenticated responses as well (if any)?!

Comment: As usual, the summary in Mark Nottingham's [Cache-Control HTTP Headers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL) is actually much easier to wrap ones head around I think, please have a look at the explanation for `public` and particularly `no-cache`, which expands on the implications of the former.