# Headers to prevent 304/If-modified-since/HEAD requests

Tags: cache, http-headers

What headers should I be sending to outright stop all requests to the server after the content has been cached?

We have a very high latency server (Sigh, VMWare) so even sending a `HEAD` request to the server takes +40ms.

Currently these are the headers being sent/received;

#### First request

Client sends;

```
GET http://dugong:8080/Rvi24mYJkxFRGNzq73PPvgWGh1j/IMG_2071.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: dugong:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Pragma: no-cache, no-cache, no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-cache, no-cache
```

Server responds;

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.11
Date: Wed, 01 Feb 2012 14:51:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Tue, 31 Jan 2012 10:45:11 GMT
Content-Length: 14
Expires: Thu, 31 Jan 2013 14:51:51 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
```

So it sends a `Cache-Control` and `Expires` header set to 365 days in the future. Unfortunately on the second refresh it requests the object again with an `If-Modified-Since` header.

#### Second Request

```
GET http://dugong:8080/Rvi24mYJkxFRGNzq73PPvgWGh1j/IMG_2071.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: dugong:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 31 Jan 2012 10:45:11 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Response;

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Server: nginx/1.0.11
Date: Wed, 01 Feb 2012 14:58:00 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 31 Jan 2013 14:58:00 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
```

Unfortunately due to silly outdated proxy software we can't use `Keep-Alive`, or put any other servers/proxys in front of the application. We also can't improve the performance of the server and reduce the network latency. I've been trying to figure out what headers we can send to get rid of the 301 requests. I've tried using ETags but that makes no difference, it still sends a `If-modified-since` header. I've also tried removing the `Last-Modified` header but that just causes a standard GET request with no caching (Checked the logs, server still receiving requests).

Clients are a mix of Firefox (mostly), IE 7, 8 and (some) 9, Chrome and Safari but this behavior seems to be appearing in all browsers tested.

### TL;DR;

Terrible network, what headers should I send to tell clients to *never ever ever* send `If-modified-since` requests to the server to validate their cache, and keep content cached until the `Expires` header is met?

I'm probably missing something obvious but everything I try seems to yield the same results.

<sub>We have an NGINX server sat in front of our application server so I can add/remove any headers as I please. Our proxy doesn't support Keep-Alive and theirs no way to improve the attrocious network performance. Due to terrible software design the web app loads +100 resources on each page load (Yeah, enterprise software sucks) with a latency of ~40-50ms per object.</sub>

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Sending the Expires and max age headers should prevent further requests of the image. Edit: by the way, what's the deal with sending a JPG as `text/plain`?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Ahh, you've made the assumption a .jpg file is actually an image rather than a text document. Welcome to my world =) (It's actually a text file that contains 'Hello World' for my testing, the software just renames all files sequentially IMG_xxxx.jpg regardless of type. Cool huh?)

Comment: what were you using to set the http request headers?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't really control what headers user agents decide to send to you. If the file in question is in the browser's cache and it decides it need to check for a new version then it will. According to [this article](http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/caching/), these are the situations browsers will request using If-Modified-Since:

> - The cached entry has no expiration date and the content is being accessed for the first time in a browser session
> - The cached entry has an expiration date but it has expired
> - The user has requested a page update by clicking the Refresh button or pressing F5

So if you are reloading the page to test your caching, it won't work since the browser will re-request the images. Try clicking a link then another link back to the first page. If your users are regularly reloading pages then you may need to rethink your site/app structure to prevent that.

One thing that may help is adding "public" to the cache control header, i.e. `Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000`. I also [learned recently](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/can-i-set-a-variable-expires-in-amazon-s3) that an expiry date of more than one year is invalid. Since your expiry date is exactly one year, perhaps lowering that by a few days or weeks would ensure the file stays in browser caches and is not discarded.

Comment: Interesting, I'll lower the expires to 60 days and add the public flag, and see what happens. This seemed to be happening on link-clicks rather than F5s (according to Firebug and the server logs)

Comment: Technically, the [HTTP/1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) only says that "servers SHOULD NOT send Expires dates more than one year in the future" (presumably because that's a ridiculously long time before expiration) and that "approximately one year" in the future is the appropriate expiration time to send for content that is never expected to expire.

Comment: After a bit of playing around, I've concluded the 365d expiry is not affecting *our* clients however I've dropped it down to be safe, it seems the `Cache-Control: public,...` was the key to this specific situation.

Comment: Do you mean the "public" header fixed the unnecessary round-trips ? I tried it, but with no success...

Comment: @phtrivier It didn't fix the issue for me either. The client (Chrome) is still making a request that has a 304 response. Have you been able to fix it another way?

Comment: In case it's not clear from my answer, **reloading the page in your browser will request the files again**. Just click links to open pages and the browser uses its cache.

Comment: "Cache-Control: public" sort of worked here too; Chrome still has trouble in some cases it seems.

Comment: "me too" and Chrome seems very particular that the "public" parameter comes before "max-age".

Comment: In this combination, avoiding F5 reload to prevent sending the if-modified-since header totally did it: Firefox 84 (linux) + IIS 8.5 + disable sending ETag header response. max-age header > 365d had no influence, nor public . You can avoid F5 by go to the address bar (Ctrl-L) and hit enter. Thanks for the useful information I found here.

Answer (score 7):

What you want is the `immutable` keyword in your `Cache-Control` line.
Example for php:

```
header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=80000, immutable');
```

Source:
https://code.facebook.com/posts/557147474482256/this-browser-tweak-saved-60-of-requests-to-facebook/

Sadly, as of Jan 2024, this works only for Firefox and Safari, but not for Chrome and Edge. See [this page on caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-http_headers_cache-control_immutable) for the details.

Comment: Make sure you only use this when you are *sure* the file will never change. One scenario would be if you have a hash of the contents in the filename, then you can guarantee it. Also it seems [browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-http_headers_cache-control_immutable) is still not great.

Comment: That's true; the next best thing for me is setting an E-Tag and replying 304 later. It's computationally cheap (check if `$_SERVER["HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH"]` is as expected before generating the content) and if the reply (just headers) fits into a single packet, also fast.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and the Requests are definitely hitting the server for it to respond with the `304` status - I'm sending the 304 via some C# and for sure it hits the server..

I only had `Cache-Control: private` set.  No `max-age` and no `Expires` It operated as expected; hit the server with the `If-Modified-Since` where I test the value compared to what I expect and deliver `304` w/empty response body - else `200` & full the response body.

Setting `Expires` header had the desired results, `200 - (from cache)` on client & no HTTP requests hit the server.

But.. I found that setting **BOTH** `max-age=` & `Expires` can cause browsers to not send `If-Modified-Since` header **AND** not to cache at all *if the values don't match*.

Something to be aware of if you have caching issues & used the different headers in combination.

Answer (score 1):

A little off-topic but maybe helpful.
Another improvement for your requests of cached content, is to cache in sessionStorage so that you don't need to ask server to validate cache and receive a 304.
Look for example google, open the console and write sessionStorage. You will see that they are caching CSS or DOM with the sessionStorage. ofc, you cannot use that in old IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Look through your source code and ensure there are no META REFRESH to transition to another page.  Use something like sendRedirect instead.  On my setup META REFRESH produces 304s in IE, but not Chrome.  sendRedirect does not produce this on either browser.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='nextpage'" />
```

vs

```
<% response.sendRedirect("nextpage") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking for answer similar to this.My scenario was I was using Apache httpd for reverse proxying a back-end service.

We wanted to introduce a `shared disk caching` at the proxy server.Problem was whenever the page was refreshed or browser cache was re-validating against server it was completely ignoring the cache we stored at the server(even though it was cached).

We found out that the browser was explicitly passing `max-age=0` in case of "f5" or "enter" and `cache-control no-cache` in case of `ctrl+f5` and this was getting forwarded by the proxy server to downstream. We stopped this behavior using `CacheIgnoreCacheControl to on`